# Increasing span limits in Sentry python

Tags: python, django, sentry

I tried to increase the limit of span by setting up `_experiments: {"max_spans": 5000}` in the `sentry_sdk.init()` but the trace doesn't appear on the sentry server if i try to capture a small trace it works.

Any ideas if there is any limit enforced on server side too?